# Silverlight 4.0 App with role-based access control on field level

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm new here.
I am currently working on a Silverlight application (SL4) with Ria Services. I use the MVVM pattern. My question is, has anyone any experience or idea, whether it is possible to implement a role-based access control at the field level. Both sides should it be dynamic. Permissions of a role should be adapted for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely.
Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449.aspx) article, at section 'Defining Access and profile properties'.

Answer (score 0):

I support field level access in my application.
[fine-grained permissions; PrincipalPermission - roles seperate from permissions;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760166/principalpermission-roles-seperate-from-permissions)

I had to create my own code access security attribute and a view to assign permissions to roles.

I discovered that permissions are hierarchical in nature.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Permission](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [applicationmodule_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [action] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
```

SecurityModuleAccess -> UpdateUser -> ResetPassword

Something that may help in assigning permissions to roles  #TreeListView
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeListView/FirstLook